# use of Static variable in mapreduce programs

Tags: java, multithreading, hadoop, static, mapreduce

I'm actually coding a program on hadoop. On my reduce task i have to use a static variable because i want it to be edited by many threads (these threads are called from the reduce fonction). 
The problem is that this variable is beeing edited by the threads of the current reduce task and also by the threads of the other reduce tasks, and i want to avoid this.

So my question is: is there a way or a trick to use to modify this variable by only the threads of the current reducer ?

I hope that my question is clear enough to help you to help me ;).

Thank you very much stack-community :)

Answer (score 0):

You may be wanting to review the "shared nothing" aspect of map/reduce programs. They are not intended (and in fact are not able..) to share JVM objects - including static variables.

The reducers would typically be mostly independent of each other. They operate on a particular partition of the data that has been processed in the Mapper stage.

In unusual circumstances there is still the opportunity to use Counters to share data across Reducers. However it is more likely that you would want to study existing map/reduce programs and see how they maintain the separation across reducers .

Answer (score 0):

thank you javadba,
you said that the reducers are independent, yes but if more than one reducer are exucuted on a same node then static variables will be shared.
So the solution i used it may helps others is that i used differente varialbes for each reducer according to the number of unique key.
For exemple if in my first program I had declared  $public static int x; $ so to avoid the problem I cited above i declare  $public static ArrayList x; $ and each element from this ArrayList is dedicated to a unique reducer.